# How to track parent/child trades in executions

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am exiting open trades with market orders and am having trouble linking the exit with the entry. In this example I am exiting order 201 with order 208 and linking by way of the m_parentid.

```
entry_orderid_ = 201

order = IBOrder()
order.m_orderId = 208
order.m_orderType = 'MKT'
order.m_totalQuantity = 1

order.m_action = "SELL"
order.m_transmit = True

order.m_parentid = entry_orderid_


log.info("Placing market exit order. {} {} {}.".format(order.m_action, 1, 'ES'))
print '.....placing order..'
try:
    app.con.placeOrder(order.m_orderId, self.contract, order)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

This executes successfully but in the executions method I have no way of tracking the parent child relationship

```
ex = msg.execution

parent_order = ex.m_parentid
```

This results in an exception. It also allows me to exit an entry multiple times. I would think it wouldnt let one close out an already closed trade. I suppose my question is how does one track the parent-child/entry and exits through executions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using parentId properly.  It's for other types of orders where the parent fill will trigger the child order.

> int   ParentId [get, set]     The order ID of the parent order, used for
>   bracket and auto trailing stop orders.

eg. https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/bracket_order.html

You also seem to be using ibpy, there is a newer api from IB.  http://interactivebrokers.github.io/#

You can't 'link' buy and sell orders like that with the api, you'll have to keep track by yourself.  That being said, your satements will show open and close and the commissionReport will show the closed trade profit if possible.

Answer (score 0):

the attribute was spelled incorrectly, m_parentId instead of m_parentid. Unfortunately now there is a new problem. IB cannot find the order to bind to

```
 ERROR - Error: <error id=1094, errorCode=135, errorMsg=Can't find order with id #
```

Answer (score 0):

You first send an order with Transmit=False, then for the next order set the parentId parameter (id of the first order) and submit with Transmit=True.

For what you need, you could always set the orderRef attribute for orders and keep track of them that way.

Answer (score 0):

The errorCode=135 (Can't find order with id XYZ) might happen in case you are trying to submit modified child order (from your original bracket order), and that child order refer to the parent order ID, which was 100% filled, thus no longer exist for IB. Example: you placed bracket order to buy stock (parent order) and 2 children: "stop loss" (SL) and "take profit" (TP). Now parent order is filled and price moved a bit. If you leave it all "as is", then eventually either your TP or SL orders will be executed.. but if you now try to move SL price (for example to break-even), then re-sending your SL order with modified price (with the parent_id field still pointing to the "no longer existing" parent order id) would trigger that error.

As a workaround: when changing your SL order price level also set the parent order id to zero!
But before setting it to zero I'd rather check if parent order was actually 100% filled (if parent order got partial fill, then obviously it still exists).

Also note: as soon as you submit your SL with parent id = 0, you brake the original "relation" (one cancel another) between your 2 children orders: SL and TP, so it is now your responsibility to track both and cancel one when another got filled.